# Magento 2.4 - AdapterFactory Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, php-7.3

I have PHP 7.3.24 installed,
After upgrading to Magento 2.4.1 I am getting the following error -

I have upgraded the MagePlaza extensions.

```
{"0":"Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\\Search\\Model\\AdapterFactory.","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() 
called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:170]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:276]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:239]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Fulltext\/Collection.php:207]\n#17 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection->__construct() called at 
[generated\/code\/Magento\/CatalogSearch\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Fulltext\/Collection\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#18 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor->__construct() 
called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create() called at 
[generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/CollectionFactory.php:43]\n#22 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\CollectionFactory->create() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/Layer\/Category\/ItemCollectionProvider.php:36]\n#23 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\Layer\\Category\\ItemCollectionProvider->getCollection() 
called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Layer.php:146]\n#24 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Layer->getProductCollection() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:481]\n#25 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:121]\n#26 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->_getProductCollection() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:366]\n#27 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->getIdentities() called at 
[generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct\/Interceptor.php:113]\n#28 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct\\Interceptor->getIdentities() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php:96]\n#29 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at 
[generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:347]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php:258]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php:171]\n#34 
Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#35 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent() 
called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#37 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at 
[generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:95]\n#38 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult() called at 
[vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n#39 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#40 
Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:263]\n#41 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at 
[pub\/index.php:40]\n","url":"\/bubble-mailers.html","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"80b6849c9a1e77cc1e929c0bd11d00a4991892f56c951d002612c4d54e69086a"}
```

Comment: Looks like this error is caused form Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation extension. By the way did you run setup:di:compile ?

Comment: I have updated the Mageplaza extensions. I get a new error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your Mageplaza extension, the version you are using uses mysql search, mysql search has been deprecated in 2.4 in favor of ElasticSearch.

Comment: i have a new error now. i am not seeing how to configure elasticsearch under configuration > Catalog > cataglog

Comment: Have you installed elasticsearch on your server?

Comment: Yes, set it up and did the nginx reverse proxy that fixed the issue.Thank you!